# Cannot add library project into my android project

Tags: android

I faced a problem when i want to add the "android-support-v7-appcompat" under my android project.

this is my step

1. File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"
2. Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"

but when in section library "Add" and choose "appCompat", there is blank and no any library for me choose.

has anyone faced this problem too and give me some suggestion? thank for help.

Comment: Given that official Eclipse support is ending in a few months, you might consider whether you should move to Android Studio. If nothing else, adding dependencies like this is a lot easier with Android Studio.

Comment: so the problem was eclipse?

Comment: AFAIK, it is still possible to add `appcompat-v7` to Eclipse. I haven't used Eclipse in over a year, so I can't say. My point is that you should be considering how much work you want to spend in getting Eclipse to behave, given that official Eclipse support is ending.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank for you suggestion, i already switch to AS, adding library was very easy in AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i was make a big mistake, for those who facing the same problem as me, please make sure

- android-support-v7-appcompat->properties->android, make sure the "Is Lirary is checked"

so you able to add the android-support-v7-appcompat under your android project.